# Left join fetch and prefetching

Tags: java, database, jpa, left-join

I have a question , when we have a query like Select DISTINCT A from A a left join fetch a.b
JPA will bring the object A populated, and the object b, which is a oneToMany relationship with a, will be prefetched. What exactly means being prefetched, because when i debug this object it has null values, and there is data in the database, so i am assuming that it is a proxy object. Does the proxy contain any data that was prefetched from the database, and it only gets populated on a.b when i actually call a method like  a.getB().size()?

I thought that if i used the "left join fetch" i wouldn't need to call a.getB().size(), but if i don't do this, the object b will remain as a proxy,and then in the presentation layer if any object call any attribute of b, there is a nullpointer.

I might add as well that this b object is mapped as being lazily loaded, that's why i am using the fetch afterall. :)  Also, even if i am using "left join fetch" and call a.getB().size(), it would not do any aditional queries right? the prefetching would be responsible for getting all of b's data,... it only needs me to call a method so it transfers the data from the proxy to the actual object?

thanks in advance for any explanation, this is really bothering me...

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your JPA implementation.

As far as I know, at least with EclipseLink, if you use a join fetch, the attribute will always be instantiated, never null.

Comment: Hi @James , I use eclipseLink, but it won't load the values after the query. When i debug the list, there is the following message "IndirectList: not instantiated". It will only fill the object when i call some of its methods, which i find weird, since i thought that using fetch it would fill the objects after the query. I am trying to understand here if the fetch is only used to optmize the query, and so even using it, i will always have to call some object's method after?

Comment: No, it should be instantiated.  Perhaps include your query.  It is not a read-only query or such?

Comment: Select DISTINCT p from P as p left join fetch p.rub join pab.rec as rec join rec.slc as slc left join fetch slc.cts  This is the query. I don't know what you mean by "read-only". I am a begginner using JPA, i don't know much yet. Sorry. :(  rub is a @OneToMany relationship with P, rec is a @ManyToOne relationship with P, slc is a @ManyToOne relationShip with rec and cts is a @OneToMany relationship with slc

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue of DISTINCT clause, Because here u have  mapping like A->B, So in the result set you might have multiple results of A for B. Use Set collection to populate the data.